# Ввод десятичных чисел с клавиатуры андроид. Как скрыть запятую?

Tags: java, android, input, decimal

В приложении есть поле EditText, куда можно вводить только числовые значения. Прописал полю свойство

```
android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

Теперь по нажатию открывается такая клавиатура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Андроид хочет разделителем точку. При вводе десятичного числа, пользователи, как нормальные люди, нажимают запятую, которая, естественно игнорируется, `просто не нажимается`. Получается, что при вводе, например 2,56 у них получается 256.
Вопрос: как скрыть запятую на клавиатуре или сделать, чтобы она тоже воспринималась приложением как разделитель дробной части?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать изменить inputType на

```
 android:inputType="date"
```

Тогда и запятых не будет и точки будут активны.

Comment: так в том-то и проблема, что запятая просто не нажимается! Добавил в вопросе.

Comment: Вот так поставьте. Там запятых нет и точки работают  android:inputType="date"

Comment: Во, то что надо. Спасибо.

Comment: Ответ измените, плз

Comment: @DrMcSheen готово